# How to execute one single query to sum 3 types of discounts?

Tags: mysql

I have the following fields in my tbl_invoices

```
Invoice_Discount_Type | Invoice_Discount
----------------------------------------
null                  | null
84                    | 750
84                    | 1500
144                   | 7
0                     | 25
144                   | 2
0                     | 16
---------------------------------------
```

Where

0 stands for percentage discount. e.g.: 25%

84 stands for Lebanese Pound discount. e.g. 750 LBP

144 stands for US dollar discount. e.g.: 7 USD

What I want to do is, execute a single query and sum all discounts for a specific date (say for example 2015-12-27) and return the result in LBP (1 USD = 1500 LBP).

Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: Yes. You can do this with a CASE statement

Comment: @Strawberry I tried a CASE statement, but it didn't work

Comment: You have two time 84, 144, 0 how this are select,  seems your schema is not complete, please provide more info and a more clear example..

Comment: @scaisEdge the information are clear. 84, 144, and 0 are 3 different types of discounts. I have thousands of invoices in the table, each invoice might/might not have a discount. In my example there are 7 invoices 1 with no discount, 2 with LBP discount, 2 with USD discount, and 2 with % discount.
What I wanna do is convert all non-Lebanese discounts to LBP, sum everything up, and display one single result.

Comment: show me the result  you want obtain for this seven invoices..

Comment: @scaisEdge
The exchange rate for 1USD in LBP 1500LL

The second and third row are already LBP (84) so we add them up: 750+1500= 2250
The fourth row is in USD (144) so we convert it to LBP then add it to the previous result (2250) - 7*1500= 10500 + 2250 = 12750
etc

Comment: I can't see any evidence of a case query (or any kind of attempt to solve this) above. And yes, you really do need to provide a primary key.

Comment: @Strawberry the table has a primary key (Invoice_ID)

Here is my query:

SELECT
 SUM(CASE i.Invoice_Discount_Type
     WHEN 84 THEN i.Invoice_Discount
        WHEN 144 THEN (i.Invoice_Discount * 1500)
    END)
     AS Discount
FROM
 tbl_invoices i
WHERE
 i.Invoice_Date = '2015-12-27'

It worked just now. I added included the CASE within the SUM function

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are looking for somethings like this

```
select sum(  
   case 
      when invoce_Discount_type = '84' then invoce_discount
      when invoce_Discount_type = '14' then invoce_discount  * 1500
   END
)  AS Discount 
from your_table;
```

Comment: It worked when I included it within the SUM function

SELECT
 SUM(CASE i.Invoice_Discount_Type
     WHEN 84 THEN i.Invoice_Discount
        WHEN 144 THEN (i.Invoice_Discount * 1500)
        WHEN 0 THEN (i.Invoice_Sub_Total - i.Invoice_Net_Total)
    END)
     AS Discount
FROM
 tbl_invoices i
WHERE
 i.Invoice_Date = '2015-12-27'

Thanks for your time @scaisEdge